# Why can't author roll back another's edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I just had someone edit a highly-voted answer I'd posted long ago, in a way the made it subtly less correct.

Why did I have to manually edit it to fix it?  Why wasn't I allowed to roll back the bad edit?  Looking through the edit history, I see "rollback" [sic] links only on the edits I made, but not on the ones made by others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You as an author can roll back just fine on your own posts.

I'm not sure what might be wrong on your side, but I see the rollback link just fine:

[image: rollback link circled on revision before last edit]

Note that the link appears on the revision you'd want to restore to, not on the top-most edit (because that's not something you can roll back to).

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was thinking of each section as an edit rather than a snapshot, and I wanted to undo the edit.  UI design is hard.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I think there's a different Stack Exchange site for that ;)